# Embedding Python: ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, c++

I'm new to Python and trying to embedd it in my c++ application.

For this i follow the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding). But when i try to execute the program i get following output:

```
ImportError: No module named 'multiply'
Failed to load "multiply"
```

My filestructure looks like this:

```
$/Documents/pytest/
$/Documents/pytest/multiply.py
$/Documents/pytest/call.cpp
$/Documents/pytest/call
```

Assuming I'm in "$/Documents/pytest/" for execution, I use this command:

```
./call multiply multiply 2 3
```

When in execute `print(sys.path)` in a python prompt i get the following output:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python34.zip', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

Why can't Python find the .py file/the module?

Comment: Maybe the simple reason is that the directory is not in the path!? I think that `'.'` is only part of the path when running interactively for convenience reasons.

Comment: oh hell no, that worked, i tried that before, but without any change, but now it works, thank you